# find command not printing files with .wav extension as specified

Tags: linux, bash, find

I've tried using this command to recursively search a folder and print .wav files, showing only the file names (not the location):

```
find /location/Master_Folder/ -type f -printf "%f\n" -iname *.wav > Wav_files.txt
```

I've also tried putting .wav in double quotes like so:

```
find /location/Master_Folder/ -type f -printf "%f\n" -iname "*.wav" > Wav_files.txt
```

When I check the Wav_files.txt file there are also .xml files listed. I only intend to print the .wav files- What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /location/Master_Folder/ -type f -iname '*.wav' -printf "%f\n"  > Wav_files.txt
```

Put the conditions (`-type` and `-iname`) before the actions (`-printf`).  `find` evaluates generally left to right, so the `-printf` happened before the `-iname` was checked in your original command lines.

Also, I tend to use single quotes `''` around patterns in `find` just so I don't surprise myself if I ever search for a filename containing a `$` (which would cause expansion within `""`). :)